# How to use dylib library in exe project in Mac using XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode3.2

I am very new to Xcode and Mac.
I have created 2 projects in Xcode. Both are C++.

1. Creating a library (Standard Dynamic Library).
2. Using that library in other exe (Command Line Tool).
3. By using standard templates I have created a dynamic library in C++ in Xcode.
4. How to use that dylib in my exe project???

Tried googling. Got something, but didn't understood anything.

Please explain step by step procedure to include dylib in exe project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you point us to the pages you didn't understand. Maybe anyone can explain in different terms.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233381/linking-and-using-a-c-library-with-an-objective-c-application
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777641/copying-dynamic-library-dylib-into-a-framework-framework
4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c
5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637081/how-can-i-link-a-dynamic-library-in-x-code
6. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720312/how-do-i-reference-a-dylib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212477/creating-a-dll-on-a-mac-dylib-or-framework
8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408725/mac-creating-simple-dylib
9. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129022/how-to-access-and-use-a-dylib-in-an-obj-c-application
10. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169398/how-do-i-modify-the-install-name-of-a-dylib-at-build-time
11. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677044/how-to-use-dylib-in-mac-os-x-c